# How should I create the function that provides the residuals for fitting of impedance data using scipy.optimize.least-squares?

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I would like to use the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm implemented in the least-squares function of Scipy's optimize module to fit measured impedance data. However, I'm a little confused about how to provide the residuals.

In the example shown in the documentation, it's clear that you should only provide the subtraction between the experimental and calculated values. So instead of creating a function that returns [image: sqr], we should write one that returns an array of [image: sqrs2].

While this is straight forward for normal data, I'm not sure how to do this for impedance data. Each impedance measurement (Z) has a real and a complex part, so the objective function becomes [image: imp] where `wt` is the weight factor, `w` is the frequency (independent variable) and `a` is the set of parameters to find. The problem is that I don't know how to correctly provide the residuals to the least-squares function as I don't think [image: imp2] would work.

Answer (score 2):

The last example in [the `scipy.optimize.least_squares` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) shows how to deal with complex residuals. Namely, if you have complex input and output:

```
def f(z):
    return z - (0.5 + 0.5j)
```

you can wrap the function to expand to two real numbers:

```
def f_wrap(x):
    fx = f(x[0] + 1j*x[1])
    return np.array([fx.real, fx.imag])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did check the last example; however, the least_squares function it's being used in a different way. In the example, they just find the values of the real and complex parts while I want to solve a curve fitting problem.

Comment: @JaffXXI Since the `least_squares` method squares the residuals, this wrapped function is equivalent to the form of the objective function you wanted, without the `wt` of course. Ultimately, the input to the function are the parameters of your fitted curve, and the output is the difference between it and your known data.

Comment: Thank you @merv. Is it possible to include a weight factor?